# 'in()' works as expected, but 'not in()' does not

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two column table (n and p), where half the n values exist in p and the other half do not. The following code returns 'NULL' instead of returning the half of the n values which are not in p.

```
select  n
from bst
where n 
not in 
(
    select p from bst
)
order by n
;
```

But when the keyword 'not' is removed, everything works as expected. Why is this code returning no values?

Comment: what are the data sets? if the is no n not in p from bst then this is expected

Comment: If `select p from bst` contains nulls then `not in` will evaluate to false. `in` works differently. It returns true if there are matches even if there are nulls too. That's why you see the difference.

Comment: @wolfrevokcats - almost. If `p` is `null`  then the condition will evaluate to `unknown` - but the net effect is the same. The condition must evaluate to `true` for the row (the `n` value) to be included in the result.

Comment: To fix it: ADD `where p is not null` to the subquery in the `in` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend using `not exists` instead of `not in` with a subquery:

```
select bst.n
from bst
where not exists select p from bst bst2 where bst2.p = bst.n)
order by bst.n
```

Why?  Because the two are not equivalent.  If any value of `p` is `NULL`, then `NOT IN` returns no rows at all.  `NOT EXISTS` has more expected behavior.

Of course, you could fix this problem by filtering in the subquery:

```
select bst.n
from bst
where bst.n not in (select bst2.p from bst bst2)
order by bst.n;
```

But I think it is easier just to remember to use `not exists` rather than `not in`.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table bst(n number, p number);

insert into bst values(null,null);
insert into bst values(2,2);
insert into bst values(null,3);
insert into bst values(4,null);
insert into bst values(5,5);
insert into bst values(11,6);
insert into bst values(null,7);
insert into bst values(13,8);
insert into bst values(14,null);
insert into bst values(15,10);

commit;

select * from bst;
```

Output:

```
N   P
 -   - 
2   2
 -  3
4    - 
5   5
11  6
 -  7
13  8
14   - 
15  10

select n from bst where n not in (select p from bst);
```

Output:

```
No rows fetched

select n from bst where n not in (select p from bst where p is not null);
```

Output:

```
N
14
15
11
4
13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select n from bst 
where n not in
( select coalesce(p,0)     from bst )
order by n ;
```

Coalesce will return 0 if p is null. You can write another value in place of 0. Write value that cant be in n.